# Want to report on calendar alarms in OS X (10.8-9)

Tags: macos, cocoa, calendar, eventkit, alerts

I want to do my own reporting of calendar events that generate alerts, but here's a lot of ambiguous nomenclature around "calendars", "events", "notifications" and "alarms".

The type of alert I'm talking about is the kind you would set up in iCal/Calendars, that automatically puts up a dialog box, plays a sound, sends an e-mail, etc. and not Reminders.

I've already got code that uses EventKit and `NSCalendar` to get my current calendar, grab all events between certain dates, and extract things from them.  So I can do all that kind of manually, checking for appropriate events, firing off my own alarms at particular times, sleeping for a while, checking again, and so on.

But from the research I've done I *think* there's a way to get an event notification (as in an OS event... there's that ambiguity again) when a calendar alarm goes off.  I've found ways to *create* an alarm (`EKAlarm`), but no way to sit around waiting for one. I also found `NSUserNotificationCenter` which seems like might enter into this, but I haven't found out if it does, and if so, how.

Just to be clear, I'm looking to intercept *calendar* alerts, *not* reminders.  And if alerts get forwarded to their usual destination as well, that's fine too (I'm not greedy!).

Can anyone help me figure out how the pieces fit together (or if it's even possible to do)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t researched this much but I would be very surprised if there’s a way for you to jump in between the calendar daemon and the notification server. It’s not the kind of hook Apple would normally provide. But my experience is with the older calendar APIs (from 10.6-), not EventKit.

Comment: I'm kind of afraid of that... but in some of my infrequent forays into Mac internals there seemed to be system events flying all over the place.  Was kind of hoping a calendar alarm might come under that category.  If not, I can still do it manually.

Comment: Event Kit is worse in terms of real usefulness. It's a crappy port of the crappy ios API. On OS X if you don't get allowed access the first time it is requested the system pop up never appears again. Instead users are expected to magically go to system preferences and changing settings there doesn't work well.